# How to get an integer from a sequence of integers by only using addition and subtraction

Tags: algorithm, numbers, dynamic-programming

For example given a sequence like 4, 10, 4, 7 and we need to get 10. The answer is 4+10-4=10. What kind of approach it's recommended to use. Can i solve it with DP? Thank you!

Comment: yes, you have to find the integer as soon as possible...if it's possible

Comment: order should be preserved?

Comment: yes, it should be preserved. first you can only use 4. I mean -4 or +4. Then, 10. -4-10 , -4+10, 4-10 or 4+10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing to a dynamic programming algorithm that comes to my mind is the following (Python):

```py
def find_number(numbers, goal):
    # sum 0 can be reached with empty sequence
    found = {0: []}
    # iterate over all numbers in the list
    for n in numbers:
        # update dict of found numbers with m+n and m-n for each m in found
        found = dict([(m + n, path + [+n]) for (m, path) in found.items()] +
                     [(m - n, path + [-n]) for (m, path) in found.items()])
        # check whether the goal number is among them
        if goal in found:
            return found[goal]
```

Other than the recursive tree-traversal algorithm, this might have the advantage of preventing some double work, as intermediate results (the numbers that can be reached up to some number in the sequence) are stored in a hash map. (That is, if some number can be reached using multiple combinations of the first `k` numbers, only one of them is stored in the map.) Further optimization could be done by dismissing intermediate results which can not possibly reach the goal even when adding or substracting the sum of all the remaining numbers.

Still, just as the recursive approach, the worst-case complexity (both time and space) and probably even the average-case complexity is still exponential in the length of the list, as the size of the `found` map can double in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example in JavaScript. You can change the numbers in the sequence if you want. It will log the result only if there is a match.

```
var sequence = [4, 10, 4, 7],
    tree = []

for (var i=0; i<sequence.length; i++){
  tree.push([sequence[i], -sequence[i]])
}

function findMatch(arr, match, numSoFar, path, iterations){
  var numSofar1 = numSoFar + arr[iterations][0],
      numSofar2 = numSoFar + arr[iterations][1],
      path1 = path + (arr[iterations][0] > 0 && iterations > 0 ? "+" : "") 
              + String(arr[iterations][0]),
      path2 = path + (arr[iterations][1] > 0 && iterations > 0 ? "+" : "") 
              + String(arr[iterations][1])

  if (numSofar1 == match) console.log(path1)
  else if (numSofar2 == match) console.log(path2)
  else if (iterations < arr.length-1){
    findMatch(arr, match, numSofar1, path1, iterations + 1)
    findMatch(arr, match, numSofar2, path2, iterations + 1)
  }
}

findMatch(tree, 10, 0, "", 0)
```